# Wordpress selected() does not save value in Dropdown-Box

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown, selected

I am trying to use the selected() function from Wordpress but I do not get it to work. I created a metabox and have a dropdown box there. If a user saves the page, the value is submitted to the database and is working fine.

The only thing that I do not get to work is, that the selected value is also displayed at the metabox once I save the page. It always shows the first entry "Default".

My code:

```
<?php $metaheader = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta-option-header', true); ?>

<select name="meta-option-header" id="meta-option-header" class="form-control" title="Show Header">
    <option value="0" <?php selected( $metaheader, '0', false ); ?>>Default</option>
    <option value="1" <?php selected( $metaheader, '1', false ); ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="2" <?php selected( $metaheader, '2', false ); ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue by myself.

Changed:

```
<?php $metaheader = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta-option-header', true); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php $metaheader = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta-option-header', true); ?>
```